# Compiling java code in OS X Terminal without cd

Tags: java, terminal

When I run

```
javac 'path/to/test.java'
java 'path/to/test'
```

I get an error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/test (wrong name: test)
```

It works when I do the same after I run "cd path/to", but is there a way to do this without the cd command? If so, how?

Comment: The `path/to/Test.java` needs to be relative to a sourcepath. The `java` command doesn't take a path, it takes a fully-qualified class name - periods, not slashes. It is relative to a classpath. (And the class name should start with an upper-case letter.) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.htmlhttps://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html

Comment: @bphilipnyc, There's nothing wrong with learning how the command-line tools work.   An IDE is great for editing, and for _manually_ running unit tests, but if your checkins are built and tested and packaged by a continuous integration system, then sooner or later you're going to need to understand the command-line tools.

Comment: I haven't run javac in like 10 years.  No harm in it of course, but you're better off spending that time learning true programming principles.

Comment: It will also identify some common syntax errors that newer programmers commonly make... OP could be missing a package statement, for example, that could have been caught by just about any IDE (see @stackoverflowuser2010's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your `Test.java` file should have a `package` line at the top:

```
package path.to;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
    }
}
```

Then you can compile and run it. It works on my MacBook Pro. Note that `java path.to.Test` and `java path/to/Test` are [equivalent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html).

```
% javac path/to/Test.java
% java path.to.Test
```

If you are **missing** the `package` statement, then you will get the error that you are reporting.

```
% javac path/to/Test.java
% java path.to.Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/Test (wrong name: Test)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `java path.to.Test`?

Comment: @Andreas: `java path.to.Test` and `java path/to/Test` are equivalent in this context. I'll modify the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to compile and run the class from your current location (presumably a project directory), I would recommend:

1. Use a package declaration in your class:

   ```
   package path.to;

   public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("LOADED");
       }
   }
   ```
2. When you run your code do so with dot notation to the class name:

   ```
   javac path/to/Test.java
   java path.to.Test
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `test.java` does not have a `package` statement, your class (which should be named `Test`, not `test`) is in the unnamed package, so do this:

```sh
javac 'path/to/test.java'
java -cp 'path/to' test
```

If your `test.java` file starts with a `package to;` statement, then you do this:

```sh
java -cp 'path' to.test
```

And if it says `package path.to;`, then you do this:

```sh
java path.to.test
```

or this to be explicit:

```sh
java -cp . path.to.test
```

If your package statement says any other name, then your directory structure is wrong, since the directory must match the package statement, starting at the directory named in the classpath (`-cp`).

Comment: Thanks! But what if I did have a package statement?

Comment: @stacko That depends on what the `package` statement says.